# Not getting new iOS Gmail notifications

Tags: ios, gmail

I haven't changed any of my notifications settings but from today Gmail notifications (from Gmail iOS app) have stopped and I'm not alerted to new emails. Only when I open the app, new emails are loaded. The badge is not being updated with the count of new emails.

I've already updated iOS for iOS 13.4 and I've already checked that there are no updates for Gmail app.

Could anyone help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: What are your notification settings in Gmail app and in the Settings app?

Answer (score 1):

See that all your setting according to this.[image: See that]